# Strange unrecognized control sequence error with beamer

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, bibtex

I was trying to include bibliography in my presentation, but I get this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\beamer@sort #1#2->\long \def \beamer@todo 
                                           {#1}\def \beamer@ospec {}\beamer@...
```

I get this error when I run pdflatex second time, the first run completes with no errors and references appear in the bibliography.

My bibliography looks like this:

```
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{References}
  \begin{thebibliography}{nevell1984unified}
    \bibitem[Bandaru and Deb, 2010]{deb10}
      Bandaru, S. and Deb, K. (2010).
      \newblock Automating discovery of innovative design principles through
      optimization.
      \newblock Technical Report 2010001, Kanpur Genetic Algorithms Laboratory,
      Indian Institute of Technology, Kanpur.

    \bibitem[Anderson, 1996]{anderson96}
      Anderson, J. (1996).
      \newblock {\em {The architecture of cognition}}.
      \newblock Lawrence Erlbaum.

  \end{thebibliography}
\end{frame}
```

I have unsuccessfully tried using bibtex to generate the bibliography but I keep getting equally strange errors, like `\newblock` unrecognized or `\item` missing from list environment etc, no matter what I do. If I remove the bibliography, everything works fine apart from the unknown citations warnings. Is there a simple working way to include the bibliography in beamer?

Comment: I'm able to compile this frame in a beamer presentation without problems. Please post a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) which produces that error.

Comment: Nevermind, I located the problem, it was the \uspackage{cite} in my preamble. After commenting it everything is working fine. Thanks.

Comment: which is why it's always a good idea to try to produce a minimal example before asking a new question. Anyway, you could post your comment as an answer and accept it, so that this question doesn't remain unanswered.

Comment: But if he had located the problem by using a minimum example by spending 15 minutes and not posted it, thousands of other users would have to do the same repeatedly wasting hundreds of man-hours. Now others can look at this answer and save time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I located the problem, it was the `\usepackage{cite}` in my preamble. After commenting it everything is working fine.